# Expand array element in quotes

Tags: gnuplot

How can I expand `np[i]` in quotes? I can also set array elements to strings such as `np[1] = "8"` if this would ease the solution.

```
array np[7]
np[1] = 8
np[2] = 12
np[3] = 16
np[4] = 20
np[5] = 24
np[6] = 28
np[7] = 32

set multiplot layout 1, 3

do for [i=1:7] {
    plot for [IDX=0:4] 'run-1/np[i].t-0.dat' i IDX u 1:2 w lines title columnheader(1)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use formatted output with `sprintf` and double quotes:

```
do for [i=1:7] {
    plot for [IDX=0:4] sprintf("run-1/%d.t-0.dat", np[i]) ...
```

Or you can use array of strings:

```
np = "8 12 16 20 24 28 32"
do for [i=1:7] {
    plot for [IDX=0:4] sprintf("run-1/%s.t-0.dat", word(np, i)) ...
```

Comment: In the second case you can directly iterate over the words: `do for [i in np] { plot "run-1/".i.".t-0.dat" }`